# How to update information on previous page of navigation controller without relaunching page?

Tags: swift, button, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, levels

I am making a quiz app and have three view controllers and I am also making use of a navigation controller. The controllers are: HomeController, LevelsController, PlayController.
The levels controller has 100 levels on it as buttons and all of them except level 1 are greyed out initially. As I complete levels, the other level buttons are unlocked and become clickable.

MY ISSUE:
This only works if I go back to the HomeController and press on the then navigate to the LevelsController again, it doesn't update instantly when I simply go back from the PlayController to the LevelsController.

This is my code in the levels controller:

```
import UIKit

class LevelsViewController: UIViewController {



    var levels = [String]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for k in globalScore...99 {
            // print("this is \(k)")
            // print(levelButton)
            levelButton[k].isEnabled = false
            print("Have the levels updated??")
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        for k in globalScore...99 {
            levelButton[k].isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet var levelButton: [UIButton]!

    @IBAction func levelSelect(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.level = sender.tag
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "LevelToPlaySegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        print("my name is jacobson")
        var vc2 = segue.destination as! PlayViewController
        vc2.enteredLevel = self.level
    }
}
```

My PlayController has a keyboard and an image that changes to a new image if the correct answer is input into a text field. I also have a score in the top right of the PlayController which is assigned to globalScore. as the global score increases, the levels page should have more levels available to the user when they go backwards from the PlayController to the LevelsController.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the PlayController? What's its purpose?

Comment: I've provided some more information and code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to change your logic and instead of using it on viewDidLoad, you should also add ViewDidAppear and ViewWillAppear, in order to call these method every time you open the viewController instead of doing it only the first time.

Comment: I have just tried this but get the same issue. When I am going backwards to the previous view controller (From PlayController to LevelsController), it it snot updated. I am required to go to HomeController and then navigate to the LevelsController again

Comment: Can you provide a lit of bit more of your code?, please

Comment: @Jasc24 provided you with the right answer. When you press "previous" on the PlayController to go back to LevelsController, ViewWillAppear gets triggered inside LevelsController. So you need to refresh your data inside ViewWillAppear. If you need more help you need to provide the code for LevelsController.

Comment: I have made some updates to the originally posted question. Please have a look.

Comment: I suggest you store current available level into a UserDefault value, then you compare with the current value once you get back to level controller. In ViewWillAppear, you get the current UserDefault, and iterate through the buttons until you get the current index, which will be the latest available level.
You have to set UserDefault in PlayController, this won't change unless you get the correct answer, and this value will remain stored on your device.

Comment: I am already using the 'globalScore' as a global variable and this is stored in user defaults and automatically updates depending on the level the user is on when in the PlayController. When you say to compare with the current value, what do you mean?

Comment: Is the globalScore equals to the latest level? If so, you can try something like this:

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {      
        for k in 1...globalScore {
            levelButton[k].isEnabled = true
        }
}

Since globalScore would become the current available level

Comment: THANK YOU! This with a couple of tweaks works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Jasc24 has answered this already but I'm writing exactly what worked for me.

I wrote this in my ViewDidLoad to make all levels except level 1 disabled:

```
for k in 1...99 {
    levelButton[k].isEnabled = false
}
```

I wrote this after the ViewDidLoad to enable specific levels only:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    for k in 0...globalScore-1 {
        levelButton[k].isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: don't forget to call super `super.viewWillAppear(animated)`